# error activity class, AndroidManifest.xml, cocos2dx

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-manifest, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to run an android project in Eclipse with cocos2d-x. I think the problem is in the AndroidManifest.xml, but I can't see where...

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.MyCompany.MyGame"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/icon">


        <activity android:name="org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="landscape"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
                  android:configChanges="orientation">

            <!-- Tell NativeActivity the name of our .so -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                       android:value="cocos2dcpp" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true"
                      android:smallScreens="true"
                      android:normalScreens="true"
                      android:largeScreens="true"
                      android:xlargeScreens="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

And that is my console:

```
[2014-11-06 19:00:18 - ProgettoLAM] ------------------------------
[2014-11-06 19:00:18 - ProgettoLAM] Android Launch!
[2014-11-06 19:00:18 - ProgettoLAM] adb is running normally.
[2014-11-06 19:00:18 - ProgettoLAM] Performing org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity activity launch
[2014-11-06 19:00:20 - ProgettoLAM] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'Maiale'
[2014-11-06 19:00:21 - ProgettoLAM] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-11-06 19:00:22 - ProgettoLAM] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-06 19:00:23 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity }
[2014-11-06 19:00:23 - ProgettoLAM] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2014-11-06 19:00:26 - ProgettoLAM] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-06 19:00:27 - ProgettoLAM] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2014-11-06 19:00:27 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity} does not exist.
[2014-11-06 19:00:30 - ProgettoLAM] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-06 19:00:32 - ProgettoLAM] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2014-11-06 19:00:32 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity} does not exist.
[2014-11-06 19:00:35 - ProgettoLAM] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-06 19:00:36 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity }
[2014-11-06 19:00:36 - ProgettoLAM] New package not yet registered with the system. Waiting 3 seconds before next attempt.
[2014-11-06 19:00:39 - ProgettoLAM] Starting activity org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity on device emulator-5554
[2014-11-06 19:00:42 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity }
[2014-11-06 19:00:42 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Error type 3
[2014-11-06 19:00:42 - ProgettoLAM] ActivityManager: Error: Activity class {com.MyCompany.ProgettoLAM/org.cocos2dx.cpp.AppActivity} does not exist.
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: AppActivity class is a part of om.MyCompany.MyGame  or org.cocos2dx.cpp.??

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean for "part of"... where do I have to look? Sorry, but it's my first project, and I can't understand where the problem is!